# How do I install mozroots?

Tags: mono

I downloaded the mozroots.1.gz file, but I don't know what to do with it.

I'm trying to install some software that is asking me to set it up by: 
$ mozroots --import --sync

Answer (score 8):

That is the `man` page. It would go in `/usr/share/man/man1/` or the equivalent location on your system.

To install `mozroots`, for example on a Ubuntu system, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

If your system uses `RPM`, in Fedora 11 for example:

```
yum provides */mozroots
```

tells me where it is which you would provide to `yum` like this:

```
su -c 'yum install mono-core-2.4-19.fc11.i586'
```